# How do i make auido player play the next song after song ended?

Tags: javascript, html, audio-player, autoplay

Im trying to implement an autoplay function into this audio player but I cant get it to work, I have been trying for ages and I feel like I wanna give up. Any help would be helpful. I am pretty new to learning javascript and hope that I will find my answer here. I somehow got it working once but then i forgot to actually save the code and it all went away and now im questioning my life's choices

````
{
    var playerTrack = $("#player-track"), bgArtwork = $('#bg-artwork'), bgArtworkUrl, albumName = $('#album-name'), trackName = $('#track-name'), albumArt = $('#album-art'), sArea = $('#s-area'), seekBar = $('#seek-bar'), trackTime = $('#track-time'), insTime = $('#ins-time'), sHover = $('#s-hover'), playPauseButton = $("#play-pause-button"),  i = playPauseButton.find('i'), tProgress = $('#current-time'), tTime = $('#track-length'), seekT, seekLoc, seekBarPos, cM, ctMinutes, ctSeconds, curMinutes, curSeconds, durMinutes, durSeconds, playProgress, bTime, nTime = 0, buffInterval = null, tFlag = false, albums = ['Anthem','Bedrin','Media','Project','La Vincenza','Flamenco'], trackNames = ['Mohammed - Mo3','Mohammed - Mo3','Mohammed - Mo3','Mohammed - Mo3','Mohammed - Mo3','Mohammed - Mo3'], albumArtworks = ['_1','_2','_3','_4','_5','_6'], trackUrl = ['http://elevarbetensys.se/SY20/Group_3/Home/music/mp3/Anthem.mp3','http://elevarbetensys.se/SY20/Group_3/Home/music/mp3/Bedrin.mp3','http://elevarbetensys.se/SY20/Group_3/Home/music/mp3/Media.mp3','http://elevarbetensys.se/SY20/Group_3/Home/music/mp3/Project.mp3','http://elevarbetensys.se/SY20/Group_3/Home/music/mp3/La_Vincenza.mp3','http://elevarbetensys.se/SY20/Group_3/Home/music/mp3/Flamenco.mp3'], playPreviousTrackButton = $('#play-previous'), playNextTrackButton = $('#play-next'), currIndex = -1;

    function playPause()
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            if(audio.paused)
            {
                playerTrack.addClass('active');
                albumArt.addClass('active');
                checkBuffering();
                i.attr('class','fas fa-pause');
                audio.play();
            }
            else
            {
                playerTrack.removeClass('active');
                albumArt.removeClass('active');
                clearInterval(buffInterval);
                albumArt.removeClass('buffering');
                i.attr('class','fas fa-play');
                audio.pause();
            }
        },300);
    }

        
    function showHover(event)
    {
        seekBarPos = sArea.offset(); 
        seekT = event.clientX - seekBarPos.left;
        seekLoc = audio.duration * (seekT / sArea.outerWidth());
        
        sHover.width(seekT);
        
        cM = seekLoc / 60;
        
        ctMinutes = Math.floor(cM);
        ctSeconds = Math.floor(seekLoc - ctMinutes * 60);
        
        if( (ctMinutes < 0) || (ctSeconds < 0) )
            return;
        
        if( (ctMinutes < 0) || (ctSeconds < 0) )
            return;
        
        if(ctMinutes < 10)
            ctMinutes = '0'+ctMinutes;
        if(ctSeconds < 10)
            ctSeconds = '0'+ctSeconds;
        
        if( isNaN(ctMinutes) || isNaN(ctSeconds) )
            insTime.text('--:--');
        else
            insTime.text(ctMinutes+':'+ctSeconds);
            
        insTime.css({'left':seekT,'margin-left':'-21px'}).fadeIn(0);
        
    }

    function hideHover()
    {
        sHover.width(0);
        insTime.text('00:00').css({'left':'0px','margin-left':'0px'}).fadeOut(0);       
    }
    
    function playFromClickedPos()
    {
        audio.currentTime = seekLoc;
        seekBar.width(seekT);
        hideHover();
    }

    function updateCurrTime()
    {
        nTime = new Date();
        nTime = nTime.getTime();

        if( !tFlag )
        {
            tFlag = true;
            trackTime.addClass('active');
        }

        curMinutes = Math.floor(audio.currentTime / 60);
        curSeconds = Math.floor(audio.currentTime - curMinutes * 60);
        
        durMinutes = Math.floor(audio.duration / 60);
        durSeconds = Math.floor(audio.duration - durMinutes * 60);
        
        playProgress = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100;
        
        if(curMinutes < 10)
            curMinutes = '0'+curMinutes;
        if(curSeconds < 10)
            curSeconds = '0'+curSeconds;
        
        if(durMinutes < 10)
            durMinutes = '0'+durMinutes;
        if(durSeconds < 10)
            durSeconds = '0'+durSeconds;
        
        if( isNaN(curMinutes) || isNaN(curSeconds) )
            tProgress.text('00:00');
        else
            tProgress.text(curMinutes+':'+curSeconds);
        
        if( isNaN(durMinutes) || isNaN(durSeconds) )
            tTime.text('00:00');
        else
            tTime.text(durMinutes+':'+durSeconds);
        
        if( isNaN(curMinutes) || isNaN(curSeconds) || isNaN(durMinutes) || isNaN(durSeconds) )
            trackTime.removeClass('active');
        else
            trackTime.addClass('active');

        
        seekBar.width(playProgress+'%');
        
        if( playProgress == 100 )
        {
            i.attr('class','fa fa-play');
            seekBar.width(0);
            tProgress.text('00:00');
            albumArt.removeClass('buffering').removeClass('active');
            clearInterval(buffInterval);
        }
    }
    
    function checkBuffering()
    {
        clearInterval(buffInterval);
        buffInterval = setInterval(function()
        { 
            if( (nTime == 0) || (bTime - nTime) > 1000  )
                albumArt.addClass('buffering');
            else
                albumArt.removeClass('buffering');

            bTime = new Date();
            bTime = bTime.getTime();

        },100);
    }

    function selectTrack(flag)
    {
        if( flag == 0 || flag == 1 )
            ++currIndex;
        else
            --currIndex;

        if( (currIndex > -1) && (currIndex < albumArtworks.length) )
        {
            if( flag == 0 )
                i.attr('class','fa fa-play');
            else
            {
                albumArt.removeClass('buffering');
                i.attr('class','fa fa-pause');
            }

            seekBar.width(0);
            trackTime.removeClass('active');
            tProgress.text('00:00');
            tTime.text('00:00');

            currAlbum = albums[currIndex];
            currTrackName = trackNames[currIndex];
            currArtwork = albumArtworks[currIndex];

            audio.src = trackUrl[currIndex];
            
            nTime = 0;
            bTime = new Date();
            bTime = bTime.getTime();

            if(flag != 0)
            {
                audio.play();
                playerTrack.addClass('active');
                albumArt.addClass('active');
            
                clearInterval(buffInterval);
                checkBuffering();
            }

            albumName.text(currAlbum);
            trackName.text(currTrackName);
            albumArt.find('img.active').removeClass('active');
            $('#'+currArtwork).addClass('active');
            
            bgArtworkUrl = $('#'+currArtwork).attr('src');

            bgArtwork.css({'background-image':'url('+bgArtworkUrl+')'});
        }
        else
        {
            if( flag == 0 || flag == 1 )
                --currIndex;
            else
                ++currIndex;
        }
    }

    function initPlayer()
    {   
        audio = new Audio();

        selectTrack(0);
        
        audio.loop = false;
        
        playPauseButton.on('click',playPause);
        
        sArea.mousemove(function(event){ showHover(event); });
        
        sArea.mouseout(hideHover);
        
        sArea.on('click',playFromClickedPos);
        
        $(audio).on('timeupdate',updateCurrTime);

        playPreviousTrackButton.on('click',function(){ selectTrack(-1);} );
        playNextTrackButton.on('click',function(){ selectTrack(1);});
    }
    
    initPlayer();
});```
````

Comment: You can make a search that goes like this. Audio player codepen. There will be a bunch of different audio players with their codes, and one of them may help.

Comment: I did that before but i couldn't find anytihng

Comment: This might help. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onended.asp

Comment: I am really sorry if it does't

Comment: sadly i couldn't figure it out :/

Comment: I'll try to modify the solution to your situation.

Comment: thank you for putting in time to help me. I really appreciate it

Comment: That's what we do here :)

Comment: I currently need to sleep if im not here when you've modified the solution to my situation. Then im probably just asleep. :)

Comment: No need to worry, it'll come in tomorrow cause right now, I really can't look at the computer screen cause I'm too tired to do so!

Comment: okie, i'll be looking forward to it

Comment: Does this link do any good? https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363891/javascript-play-audio-one-after-another-html5&ved=2ahUKEwjKvvCwmsnuAhVPFVkFHcUMClIQFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw2MZmi-3loSfm3K8jSVxy5n

Comment: I tried to implement it but didn't get it to work. bruh momento

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright, finally I have an answer. Its only two audios played one after another, and you can keep on add more and more.  The code is below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio id = "id" onended = "myFunction()">
<source src = "https://www.zapsplat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/sound-effects-41945/zapsplat_bells_church_bell_ring_12_ext_med_close_43634.mp3?_=1">

</audio>
<audio id = "audio">
<source src = "https://www.zapsplat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/sound-effects-audeption/audeption_church_bell_with_street_and_some_birds_010.mp3?_=2">
</audio>

<p>Click the buttons to play or pause the audio.</p>

<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>


<script>
var x = document.getElementById("id"); 
var z = document.getElementById("audio")

function playAudio() { 
  x.play(); 
} 

function myFunction() { 
  z.play(); 
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for how long the audio is.

Comment: You can tell where one audio ends and the other plays by the small gap in between.

Comment: ok im going to try this thank you hopefully i can do it heh

Comment: Did it work or not. It should since I tested.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this at the end, it works for me.

```js
  
  audio.addEventListener('ended',function(){
       selectTrack(1);
    });
  
  } 

  initPlayer();
});
```